# PHP; Get Serial number from Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

*Get Position of row from Pagination*

---

**all_ads.php**

Page 1 **2** 3 4

```
Sl No.  ID     Ads Name   Customer
----------------------------------
11      220    Test 1     Jennifer Lawrance
12      250    Test 2     Paul Walker
13      255    Test 3     Jennifer Lawrance
```

Sl No - Auto Increment by PHP

ID    - Unique Number for the row from MySql

**MySql query**

```
  SELECT ad.id, cust.full_name
  FROM ads ad
  INNER JOIN customer cust ON ad.customer_id=cust.id
  WHERE ad.status='active'
  ORDER BY ad.created_date ASC 
  LIMIT 20, 20
```

**my_ads.php**

After the login, Need to display the position of the Customer Ads position in the website. *I was trying to get the Sl No. of a particular field*?.

```
E.g: Sl no for Test 3 is 13
After Jennifer Lawrance Login

Sl No.  ID     Ads Name  
------------------------
11      220    Test 1    
13      255    Test 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's working for me.

```
    if(empty($pageno) || $pageno == 1){
         $srno = 1;
    }
    else{
        $temp = $pageno-1; 
        $new_temp = $temp.'1';
        $srno = (int)$new_temp;
    }
```